# Nftables rules disappeared after reboot!

Tags: debian, nftables

I tried this:

```
iptables -F
ip6tables -F

sudo nft list ruleset > /etc/nftables.conf

sudo service netfilter-persistent save
```

But after reboot when I run

```
nft list ruleset
```

I see nothing. I think that `netfilter-persistent` doesn't see my file with rules. I use Debian Buster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By itself `netfilter-persistent` does nothing, it's a plugin framework only. It does not read `/etc/nftables.conf` in particular. You should have nftables plugins installed under `/usr/share/netfilter-persistent/plugins.d` for it to work with nftables. However, I don't think such plugins are available in any package; you'll have to write them yourself (in the language you prefer).

Comment: Here's some documentation on how to integrate [nftables with netfilter-peristent](https://github.com/hardenedlinux/harbian-audit/blob/master/docs/configurations/manual-operation-docs/how_to_persistent_nft_rules_with_debian_10.mkd)